# UDK and C++, is it possible?

Tags: c++, udk

I've never used the UDK before and I am wondering: is it possible to use the UDK through C++ instead of UnrealScript?

I saw it's possible to [bind external C++ DLL's](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/DLLBind.html) to UnrealScript, but I don't know if it's possible to call engine functions from inside C++ code.

Comment: Maybe it's not possible, because of `.dll`'s raison d'etre.

Comment: Also in case you didn't know, you can use C++ with Unreal but not UDK easily

Comment: @CobaltHex: from epic site it seems only to allow me to download UDK. Where can I find UnrealEngine3? What's the license cost?

Comment: unreal engine 3 is only (afaik) licensed to AAA companies. It probably costs at least $10k

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've spotted yourself, it's possible to use C++ within the UDK thanks to `DLLBind`. But there's no way you will be able to call engine functions from C++, you'll have to glue everything together using UnrealScript.

Comment: thanks for clarify. Is there any good reason in order not allow C++ bindings to engine function in UDK?

Comment: I suppose that would render licensing UE3 less interesting for developers, and Epic doesn't want to cut that revenue stream. So not a technical reason, bur rather a business decision.

Answer (score 1):

With UDK 4.0 and higher, definitely, since UnrealScript is being replaced with direct C++ APIs. UDK 3.0 and lower, unlikely.

Comment: Woah, really? Would you be kind enough to provide any other information you have regarding this, links even? I've searched around but can't find much. Would appreciate it. **EDIT**: I've found mention of this with regards to UE 4. Do you mean this would be the case with the hypothetical UDK based on UE 4?

Comment: thank your for the answer. Could you provide some reference on direct C++ for UDK 4.0?

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña: Yes, this is the case with the hypothetical UDK shipped with UE 4.

Comment: @Heisenbug: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_Development_Kit#Unreal_Engine_4 and http://www.udk.com